# CSS issue in Internet Explorer 8 actual browser

Tags: asp.net, html, css, webforms

I am facing a design issue on a client machine which has Internet Explorer 8. On my machine, which has IE 9, I can't replicate the same design issue even when I use F12 (IE 8/7 Standard or compatible mode). The problem only happens with users who have IE 8 installed on their system.

The problem only happens with TOP Menu for all pages other than the home page, which has a different design.

[link of website](http://tinyurl.com/c99epj8)

Screen shot of the design issue in the menu part:

[image]

I would appreciate help in this regard

Comment: everything is perfect for me, tested using compatible mode in IE

Comment: did you try it on the actual IE 8 compatible & standard mode.

Comment: I tried this in IE8 but did not get the issue. In my case the width of "Library" is lot more but the menu is coming in one line.
Try by giving some fixed height to the menu. Then I think it will not come in 2 lines.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker Yup it's perfect

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove `display: inline` and `position: relative` ?

Comment: Are you able to see the design flaw & for which class are you talking about so that i can test it.

Comment: Can't see it. Talking about li elements. I don't see issue with Browserstack too.

Comment: I did remove it but it doesn't work i still have the problem. I am using `browserstack.com` to test it now i can see the problem in IE 7 & IE 8. it add space to left of the active menu for some reason.